# How to handle common functionality for all events?

Tags: powerbuilder

**Situation**: A window has user event **_Common()** that is fired from many other events of different objects in the same window to complete common functionality.

**Problem**: I have to write the "**Event _Common()**" in every object's event where i need to call _Common().

**Question**: Is there a way my **_Common()** event can be fired on any event occurred for a control. for example Datawindow control has many event and instead of writing many calls for **_Common()** i write just one call. Let's say there is one system event named **AnyEvent** in Datawindow control where i write call for my **_Common()** event. I need to know if there is option to create event like **AnyEvent** that fires on any event of Datawindow?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I do not see any possibillity to do that but maybe some other solutions are possible.  Could you explain why you need to call the routine for ALL events (mouse up and down, dragdrop, click, double click, right click, resize, move,...)?  I have it difficult to understand why you want that?

Comment: A voucher window has many controls including buttons, DDLB, DWs etc.  Almost every control take part in calculations and those calculations are based on many flags to check. i created _Common() event where i check those flags. I wrote script for mostly used events of every control in the window. most of the event like mouse move, drag drop etc are not used. The common functionality is very important for me that is why i have to have a common event to do that.

Comment: There is no big problem to write many many calls to the _Common() event but still it does not look good. There should be easy way to do that.

Comment: There’s a standard Windows event that covers this, and you can map it with PB. It was 20 years ago for me, so I’m not recalling an event name, but it’s in the WinAPI documentation somewhere. However, I’m with where I think Marc is leading: this gets called SOOO many places that my trial of this caused me to toss the idea because it slowed everything down too much. I’d go with the explicit coding; I suspect you’ll be better off in the long run.

Comment: You are right. Tracing all system events will make everything  work too slow. The base control name which fired an event and array of the desired events names which are mostly used by a control must be checked. Somehow a filter on events must be applied to avoid unnecessary calls to _Common() event. First thing to check is the event name from Win API and then I will see how to get rid of unnecessary work that slow down whole process.

Comment: I think the standard "catch all" control event that PB defines is `pbm_other`.  It will likely bog down the app, though.  So, the syntax would look something like:   `event ue_other pbm_other`

Comment: Yes Frank, help says, The Other event is no longer useful, because you can define your own user events. You should avoid using it, because it slows performance while it checks every Windows message. But the point is how to make it useful? First thing i need to understand how to name all those fired system events so i can use IF statement. Is there any way to do that?